# Why does "text-align:center" work for "div" but not for "img"?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Here is an example:

```css
p, span, div,img {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Para</p>
<span>Span</span>
<div>Div</div>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo195.png" />
<div><img src="https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo195.png" /></div>
```

I found apply `text-align: center` on `img` directly doesn't work.

Does this mean it has to be wrapped in an empty `div` when a centered image is needed?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

`text-align` aligns the text (and other inline) content inside the element to which it is applied.

There is no content *inside* an image.

You can either:

- Make the image display as a block and then use auto margins
- Put it inside any block element (it doesn't have to be a div, but that's usually the most sensible choice if you are just centring it) and set text-align on that container.

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but maybe add `text-align` to the body as a third alternative?

Comment: @jbutler483 — That's the the same the second option. The body is a block element. Generally you don't want to centre everything on the page by default, it just means having to go through and left align all your paragraphs again.

Comment: That's true I suppose. The last alternative I could think of is positioning, but again It wouldn't be overly desired as it'd mess up with the DOM flow. +1 for answering the question, but also providing an alternative, too :)

Answer (score 5):

`text-align: center` centers horizontally *inline content of the container* it is applied to. So yes, to center image (*inline* layout) inside container (*block* layout), you should apply this css to container, not image.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center an img use:

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `text-align` on img tag, use it on div

```css
p, span, div,img {
    text-align: center;
}
#testimg {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:auto;
  top:50px;
  height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="testimg">
   <img src="https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo195.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: ***what*** is with the inline styling? Also, why would you give a `top` and `bottom` declaration when you've also used `height`? There's quite a bit of 'fluff' in your answer here.

Comment: Because i use overflow is height is not specified it will hide the image. For styling it i use bottom and top...

Comment: This, I'm afraid, is a bad implementation of the `position` element. i would almost remove the `bottom` altogether, but then again there's so much that needs to be altered :( [FOR EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/sa5Lebo0/1/)

Comment: What is bad implementation of the position element?

Comment: Please see the fiddle example I've just added. Note how *none* of that is needed. Also note OP *has already* got the 'img within a div' working, it was the plain `img` tag on its own that was causing the issue!